# Regular Expression complex serie with specific pattern

Tags: regex

I will try to explain what I need help with.

The numbers in below series that I want to check by the regex, are `"2 904", "3 231", "2 653", "2 653", "2 353"` and so on. My goal is to only get a match if one of these numbers will be in format `"123"` (`3-digits`, between `100-999`)

**No match:**
sö 31 1 2 904 2 3 231 3 2 653 32 4 2 653 5 2 353 6 2 353 7 2 353 8 2 904 9 3 002 10 3 143 33 11 2 615 12 2 353 13 2 353 14 2 353 15 2 353 16 2 653 17 2 353 34 18 2 157 19 1 699 20 1 699

**Match:**
sö 31 1 2 904 2 3 231 3 **653** 32 4 2 653 5 2 353 6 2 353 7 2 353 8 2 904 9 3 002 10 3 143 33 11 2 615 12 2 353 13 2 353 14 2 353 15 2 353 16 2 653 17 2 353 34 18 2 157 19 1 699 20 1 699

sö 31 1 2 904 2 3 231 3 2 653 32 4 2 653 5 2 353 6 2 353 7 2 353 8 2 904 9 3 002 10 3 143 33 11 2 615 12 2 353 13 2 353 14 **953** 15 2 353 16 2 653 17 2 353 34 18 2 157 19 1 699 20 1 699

As you can see from my examples, number "2 653" changed to "653" just after number "3"
And number " 2 353" changed to "953" after number "14". 
Numbers between, i.e 1-20, are static numbers and will never change

Possible?

I will try it then at http://rubular.com/

Comment: So you want to get the numbers between 100 and 999. Is that correct?

Comment: `"2 904"` is NOT a 3 digit number. You probably want to explain yourself a little better.

Comment: Have you tried `[1-9]\d{2}`?

Comment: Sounds like there is a math operation in the desired result. Can you please clarify?

Comment: So you want every three-digit number and the number which precedes it? `grep -Eo '\<[0-9]+ [0-9]{3}\>' file`

Comment: Please check question again, tried to reformulate it !

Comment: I can't understand anything. What you have tried? sed? perl? If you could paste an INPUT line and desired OUTPUT, would be great.

Comment: this is a start: sö\s31\s1\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: no one that can help me ? :-( I have read about look forward in a regular expression but dont know if that can make the trick here?